# Интерфейс для объектов, с которыми можно производить арифметические операции

Tags: c#, интерфейс

Допустим я хочу написать класс подсчета сраднего арифметического:

```cs
public class AverageCounter<T> where T : INumber<T>
{
    public T Sum { get; private set; }
    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public void Add(T el)
    {
        Sum += el;
        Count++;
    }

    public AverageCounter()
    {
        Sum = default;
        Count = 0;
    }
}
```

Такой код работает, но не хватает одного свойства, с реализацией которого у меня возникли трудности:

```cs
public T Average
{
    return Sum / Count;
}
```

Какой интерфейс использовать, чтобы строчка `return Sum / Count;` не вызывала проблем?

Возможно нужно написать свой интерфейс? Но тогда как, потому что я не очень понимаю как его реализовывать...

Comment: Я с дженериками а тем более в шарпе не знаком, но всеже, кмк тут самое место для ```try catch```, как минимум по причине деления на ноль :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Так не получиться( ошибка возникает во время компиляции, так что ```try catch``` ничего не изменит. Да и даже если бы это работало, хочется отлавливать ошибку в тот момент, когда программист создает класс из элементов неправильного типа, а не в какой-то другой момент.

Comment: [Generic Math](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-7-generic-math/#generic-math) - в самом начале пример кода Average.

Comment: _подсчета сраднего арифметического_ - среднего арифметического чего? Уже есть же готовое прямо в дотнете, пользуйтесь: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average. А так, вы хотите что-то типа свойства расширения, такого не бывает в C#, есть только методы расширения. Но опять же, нужный вам метод расширения уже есть в дотнете.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да, спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: @aepot Я сейчас просто изучаю ```C#```. Хотел понять, как реализовывать подобные классы для объектов любых типов, потому что не всегда есть встроенные решения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем то все оказалось просто. Нужно было указать, что `T` реалезует интерфейсы `IAdditionOperators<T, T, T>`, `IDivisionOperators<T, int, T>`

Финальный код класса:

```
public class AverageCounter<T> 
    where T : IAdditionOperators<T, T, T>, 
    IDivisionOperators<T, int, T>
{
    public T? Sum { get; private set; }
    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public void Add(T el)
    {
        Count++;
        Sum = Sum == null?el:Sum+el;
    }

    public T Average
    {
        get { return Sum / Count; }
    }

    public AverageCounter()
    {
        Sum = default;
        Count = 0;
    }
}
```

теперь можно использовать `AverageCounter` как для `int`, `double`... Так и для, например, точек:

```
class Point : IAdditionOperators<Point, Point, Point>, 
    IDivisionOperators<Point, int, Point>
{
    public readonly double X, Y;
    
    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public static Point operator +(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        return new Point(p1.X + p2.X, p1.Y + p2.Y);
    }
    
    public static Point operator /(Point p1, int n)
    {
        return new Point(p1.X / n, p1.Y / n);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Point({X}, {Y})";
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно вместо проверки на `null` через `if/else` сделать короче в одну строку: `Sum = (Sum ?? 0) + el;`

Comment: @CrazyElf Хорошая идея сократить ```if else```, но тут ваш вариант не подойдет, так как я не могу присвоить ```0``` в ```Sum```. Я написал вот так: ```Sum = Sum == null?el:Sum+el;```

Comment: Да вроде это тоже самое будет. Но можно и через тернарный оператор, да )